# RAID10 - Clean, degraded - Missing disk

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I just checked my Raid10 status and it says "Clean, degraded".

- Why is that?
- Isn't degraded a bad thing or something?

I had 1 bad disk `/dev/sdd`, so I replaced him and clicked "Recover" and it's finished until 100%.

But it's still degraded now, And seems like another disk is missing from the raid.

[image: ss1]

```
Details:

Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Tue Apr 12 16:19:22 2016
Raid Level : raid10
Array Size : 21487212032 (20491.80 GiB 22002.91 GB)
Used Dev Size : 1953382912 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
Raid Devices : 22
Total Devices : 21
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Sun Mar 26 22:39:05 2017
State : clean, degraded
Active Devices : 21
Working Devices : 21
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

Layout : near=2
Chunk Size : 512K

Name : storage02off:storage02off (local to host storage02off)
UUID : 12ec260e:98e29218:c957740e:0e958366
Events : 154450

Number Major Minor RaidDevice State
23 8 16 0 active sync /dev/sdb 
1 8 32 1 active sync /dev/sdc
26 8 48 2 active sync /dev/sdd
3 8 64 3 active sync /dev/sde
4 8 80 4 active sync /dev/sdf
24 8 96 5 active sync /dev/sdg
6 8 112 6 active sync /dev/sdh
7 8 128 7 active sync /dev/sdi
8 8 144 8 active sync /dev/sdj
9 8 160 9 active sync /dev/sdk
10 8 176 10 active sync /dev/sdl
11 8 192 11 active sync /dev/sdm
12 8 208 12 active sync /dev/sdn
13 8 224 13 active sync /dev/sdo
14 8 240 14 active sync /dev/sdp
15 65 0 15 active sync /dev/sdq
16 65 16 16 active sync /dev/sdr
17 65 32 17 active sync /dev/sds
18 0 0 18 removed
25 65 64 19 active sync /dev/sdu
22 65 80 20 active sync /dev/sdv
21 65 96 21 active sync /dev/sdw
```

OK, I found out that I should have total of 22 disks in my array, but I only have 21. 1 of them is removed, named `/dev/sdt`. It's shown under "Physical devices" so its connected to the machine.

[image: ss2]

But, When I click ' Recover' in Raid Management, I don't see it as unused disk..

What is that?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I just had to re-add the disk to the raid. Somehow it was no longer part of it.

So I used this command:

```
$ mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --re-add /dev/sdt
```

After that the RAID just recovered itself, and now it's on 'Clean' State.